# using for loop, index out of bounds python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, indexing

I'm working on a problem that requires developing code for a context model:
 P(A|x)=∑a∈A(x,a)/∑a∈A(x,a)+∑b∈B(x,b)
which calculates the probability of that a novel stimulus x belongs to the category A. The S is a similarity function I defined earlier as:

```
def calculate_similarity(x, y, theta=0.1):
    return (np.prod([1 if x[i] == y[i] else theta for i in range(len(x))]))
```

The function takes in the test stimuli, exemplars, exemplar names and theta and wants us to return an array of the probabilities that each stimulus belongs to A.

```
def context_model(test_stimuli, exemplars, exemplar_categories, theta=0.1):
```

I know that I should be iterating over every test stimuli and calculating the similarity between it and the exemplars- I can even do this by the exemplar category name "A" and "B", but when I run my code I get and index error.

```
result = []
a_data = np.argwhere(exemplar_categories == 'A')
b_data = np.argwhere(exemplar_categories == 'B')
for x in test_stimuli: 
    a = [calculate_similarity(x, exemplars[i, :], theta) for a_data[i] in range(0, len(a_data))]
    b = [calculate_similarity(x, exemplars[i, :], theta) for b_data[i] in range(0, len(b_data))]
    final = sum(a)/ (sum(a) + sum(b))
    result = np.append(result, final)
return result
```

When I run,

```
stimuli = np.array([
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
exemplars = np.array([
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
exemplar_categories = np.array(['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'])
context_model(stimuli, exemplars, exemplar_categories, theta=0.1)
```

I get the statement "index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

I've been working on this problem for days and don't know where to go from here. I've tried applying the function to every X in the stimuli and then parsing out the A and B data, but nothing is working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! I'm still new to coding and this problem is driving me crazy.

Comment: Posting the entire traceback of the exception will be of use to anyone who wants to try an help with this question.

Comment: The error is produced when indexing a `numpy` array.  You do that with `exemplars[i,:]`, but you don't tell us anything about `exemplars` or `i`.  `a_data[I]` is also an array indexing, since `a_data` is produced by `argwhere`.  But what is `I`?  Also that `a_data[I] in range(...)` expression is weird.  I had to test it to convince myself it wouldn't produce a syntax error.  It works, but I don't understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hi! I updated the post with the test case that I'm failing. a_data[I] was a typo on my part. The 'a_data[I] in range(...)' was meant to produce a list related to the exemplar categories with title "A". So I tried to do a for loop according to the indices provides in a_data?

Comment: exemplars is a  numpy array with shape (k, m) k exemplars, each with m features